# How to view all tags in a git repository (more than 29)?

Tags: git, git-branch

I am going through a texbook on Flask (Python framework). Examples are provided in git repository: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky

Each example is a <strike>branch</strike> tag, but

```
git show-branch -a
```

does not show all of them, because as I understand the command above can only show 29 branches at once. How do I navigate through all of the examples?

Thanks

EDIT mistaken branches with tags

Comment: if you are using the above repository; there are only 2 branches...

Comment: Maybe you mean `tags`? Try `git tag` command.

Comment: I am using the one above. I made a screenshot. Am I mistaken and those are not branches? http://imgur.com/gh7JRPj

Comment: `git tag`  seems to work, but it does not show any description of examples.

Comment: Try `git log --tags` or `git log --all`

Comment: You're not looking at branches in your screenshot, you're looking at commits. Use e.g. `git log` to view them, or `git log --oneline`

Comment: thanks to everyone. it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure to see everything (branches, tags, and commits), use the refs and format options of [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
```

Comment: I use this command a lot, but I don't see the added value of the --branches option..?

Comment: @ChrisMaes I agree: if `--all` is used, `--branches` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
git tag
```

to show all tags.